# getting excel from spring rest web service to download

Tags: java, excel, spring, rest

Can I produce a excel from spring rest. Could you provide sample code:

I can see we can do with http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-excel-file-from-jax-rs/ .

Not sure what code need to write inside:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getexcel", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/vnd.ms-excel")
    public Response getFile() {

    }
```

Thanks
rAm

Comment: It appears that you are mixing JAX-RS (Response) and Spring MVC (RequestMapping) annotations.

Comment: Did you find in spring reference manual ?

Answer (score 0):

One way, (which I normally use) is to read the file and write to Outputstream (ServletOutputStream). You need to have HTTPServletResponse in your parameters.

So basically your `getFile()` should have HTTPServletResponse parameter and then in the function code, write outputstream.write();